# Live event on iFrame element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, binding, live

I spent last couple hours trying to find solution for my problem: How to make function like click on button in iframe which was dynamically created with ajax. Because .live() doesn't support this I ended up witch code like this:

```
$("#iframeID").live("mouseover", function(){
  //Unbind and bind avoids firing event twice (?don't know why jquery does this)
  $(this).contents().find("#buttonID").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e){
    //Do whatever you want
  });
});
```

No matter when the iframe is created, after being "mouseovered" it binds the click event to button inside that iframe.
This solution really works for me and I am okey with that. 
So my question is if there is some drawback in this solution.

Comment: Sometime museover in jquery run as mousemove therefore you should use mouseenter in place of mouseover and for iframe I don't see any drawback in it

Answer (score 0):

Will this not unbind and bind the event to the button every time the mouse is moved in the iFrame.. ?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but since this iframe is not very big and is loaded only in certain scenario it is not big problem for me.